# Proof that subspace topology is independent of 'parent' space

Tags: general-topology

In my topology textbook (Bert Mendelson's) it is stated that if $C$ is a subspace of two distinct larger spaces $X$ and $Y$, then the relative topology of $C$ is the same whether we regard it as a subspace of $X$ or $Y$.

In an attempt to prove this, regard $C$ as a subspace of $X$ and suppose $S$ is an open subset of $C$. Then $$S = S' \cap C$$ for some open subset $S'$ of $X$. Now I'm not sure how to continue; proving that $S' \cap Y$ is an open subset of $Y$ would do the job, since then $$S' \cap Y \cap C  = S$$ is in the topology of $C$ regarded as a subspace of $Y$, but I don't see a way to prove this.

Can anyone help me with this proof? Can $S' \cap Y$ be shown to be open in $Y$ or should I take a completely different approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By definition, a topological subspace is endowed with the subspace topology.  If $C$ is a subspace of $X$ and a subspace of $Y$, then the subspace topologies agree by definition

Comment: What is the complete formulation? E.g. One exact formulation could be: Let $X$ be a topological space, let $Y$ be a subset of $X$ in the subspace topology (from $X$). Let $C$ be a subset of $Y$. Then the subspace topology that $C$ gets as a subspace of $Y$ or of $X$ is the same. This follows easily from the definitions.

Comment: I think he means X and Y are common subspaces of a larger space...But then X∩Y is a subspace of X containing C. Using @HennoBrandsma reasoning, we are done.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have indeed seen a proof of that case, but paraphrasing the book _"A topological space $C$ may be a subspace of two distinct larger topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. In this event the relative topology of $C$ is the same whether we regard..."_

Comment: So the one is not necessarily a subspace of the other.

Comment: Both both are subspaces of a common super space I think

Comment: What do you mean by a subspace of a topological space $X$? Do you mean an injective continuous map $C\ \hookrightarrow\ X$? Or do you mean a *subset* $C\subset X$ endowed with the subspace topology?

Comment: Subset endowed with subspace topology

Comment: Then you really need the topologies of $X$ and $Y$ to be compatible somehow, for example by both being subspaces of some larger space $Z$. Otherwise you can endow a set $C$ with two different topologies, and call these spaces $X$ and $Y$, and your statement fails.

Comment: Doesn’t it really matter how the two parents are related?

Comment: Never mind I see that everyone else picked up on this.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma how would one go about the proof if $X$ and $Y$ are indeed subspaces of a superspace $Z$? $S^{'} \cap Y$ may still not be in $Y$'s topology if $X$ is not an open subset of $Z$, since $S^{'} \cap Y = X \cap S^{''} \cap Y$ where $S^{''}$ is an open subset of $Z$, but nothing ensures that $X$ is an open subset of $Z$, right?

Comment: $S$ is an open subset of $C$ vis $X$ then it is also relatively open from $Z$. And so also via $Y$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma doesn't that require $X$ to be an open subset of $Z$?

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments I'll assume the following situation: 
We have a superspace $Z$ such that $X,Y \subseteq Z$ have the subspace topology w.r.t. $Z$ and $C \subseteq X \cap Y$.

Now $C$ can inherit the subspace topology of $X$ or of $Y$, but this does not matter, because in the end it's just the subspace topology from $Z$.

If $S \subseteq C$ is open "via $X$" then $S = S_X \cap C$ with $S_X$ open in $X$, so really, $S_X = O \cap X$  where $O$ is open in $Z$. Hence $S = (O \cap X) \cap C = O \cap C$ (as $X \cap C = C$) and so $S$ is open as a subspace of $Z$. Moreover, $S = O \cap C = O \cap (C \cap Y) = (O \cap Y) \cap C$ where $O \cap Y$ is open in $Y$ (by definition of the subspace topology on $Y$) and so $S$ is also open "via $Y$". This argument is entirely symmetrical, so indeed it does not matter via which subspace $X$ or $Y$ we endow $C$ with a subspace topology. The common superspace enforces the consistency, as it were.

Answer (score 0):

We almost always talk of a top. space $X$ when we really mean a pair $(X,T_X)$ where $T_X$ is a certain kind of collection of subsets of $X$, called a topology on $X$, and  commonly called the collection of open sets. $T_X$ is not determined by $X$ alone, unless $X$ has at most one member. Suppose $T_X$ is a topology on $X$ and $T_Y$ is a topology on $Y,$ and that $X\supset C\subset Y.$ There may be many possible topologies on the set $C$. Suppose $T_C$ is a topology on $C$ such that $(C,T_C)$ is a sub-space of  $(X,T_X)$ and also of $(Y,T_Y)$. By the definition of a sub-space topology, this means that $$\{x\cap C:x\in T_X\}=T_C=\{y\cap C: y\in T_Y\}.$$